# Create Table View Style UITableViewStyleCustom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

As everybody knows, there is easy to initialise UITableViewCell:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

But how to create my own table view style definition "UITableViewCellStyleCustom"?

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answers already pointed out, there are tons of tutorials as on how to create your own cell style.

However, remember the preferred way to **create** a table view cell is to reuse one in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` like so:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

**EDIT**

If you want to implement your own version of `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`, you can obviously create your own enumeration of cell styles, e.g.:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyTableViewCellStyle){
    MyTableViewCellStyleFile,
    MyTableViewCellStyleFolder
};
```

Then you can define a custom init method like so:

```
-(instancetype)initWithMyStyle:(MyTableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;
```

Apart from that, `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` is part of the enumeration `UITableViewCellStyle` in UIKit. So it is basically just an integer value and passing a different value than the defined will not work in default init methods.

Comment: `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` is part of the enumeration `UITableViewCellStyle` in iOS' UIKit. So it is basically just an integer value. If you pass a different value than the ones defined in the enum, iOS will not understand, unless you interpret this value yourself in your own `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method. If the latter is the case, you are free to use whatever value you want. Just create your own.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions for this:

1. You prototype your own custom cell on a storyboard. This is a quick way of creating a custom cell without too much of a hassle. If I am not mistaken this is not available in NIBs.
2. Create your Cell in a NIB.

On both approaches, you will have to then subclass a `UITableViewCell` and add the behaviour you want to it. You will also need to specify on the Storyboard or Nib, that you want that cell to have the type of the subclass you just created. There a tons of tutorials on the web on how to do it.

Comment: You see, the problem is that I have code-only project. I need to subclass UITableViewCell to make it custom. But, there are few types of possible cell. For example cell can be a file or a folder.  To implement this it would be great to pass cell style in initialisation (inside of cell, according to style definition I could create desired type custom cell).

Comment: You can, but not the way you want it to. You can simply create a method like this: `- (void)configureCellWithType:(MyType) withModel:(MyModel)model`. This method would be called after initialising the cell.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to subclass `UITableViewCell` to get a custom cell.

When initializing in code (why?), just use `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` as the `style` parameter in the designated initializer. I recommend initializing the cell via storyboard or Interface Builder.

Comment: There are few types of possible cell. For example cell can be a file or a folder. To implement this it would be great to pass cell style in initialisation (inside of cell, according to style definition I could create desired type custom cell).